# Получить аватар из инсты php

Tags: php, php7, file-get-contents

Как получить аватар из инстаграм?
пробую так, но выдает null

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1");
$insta = json_decode($response, true);
return $insta['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url'];
```

Comment: Кто выдаёт? Ваш пример работает. Возможно вы не указали какие-то детали. Это код функции? Скрипта? Как вы определяете что "выдаёт null"?

Comment: var_dump($insta)

Comment: `$insta` это результат парсинга строки `$response`. Если в `$response` не JSON, то результат, конечно будет `null`. Так что же в `$response`?

Comment: в `$response` лежит `json`, а вот что лежит в `$insta`?

Comment: перейдите по ссылке https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1 там будет json мне нужно оттуда забрать аватар

Comment: @Uvasya если перейти по ссылке, то json получит код, написанный разработчиками браузера. Для решения вашей проблемы нужно узнать что получит именно ваш код. Просто напишите у себя `var_dump($response)` и взгляните на вывод. Скорее всего ваш код не может получить этот json (не распарсить, а именно получить результат запроса).

Comment: Странно, у меня вылезла аватарка, правда я с локалки стучался. По идее инстраграмм еще может заблочить ваш ip за множественное обращение.

Answer (score 0):

Используя метод `file_get_contents()` вы получаете ВСЕГДА ответ в виде `string`, в случае успеха, разумеется. Картинка в виде строки представляет бинарный код `BLOB`, что вы и получаете. Можно воспользоваться методом `imagecreatefromstring()` в библиотеке **GD**, которая по умолчанию идет с PHP. Можете проверить есть ли она у вас, на счет этого загуглите, ибо в 99% случаев она уже имеется.

Следующий код сохранит картинку с именем `download.jpg` в корневую директорию:

```php
<?php

$url = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/O8dx0V3F1sI/maxresdefault.jpg';

if($response = file_get_contents($url)) {
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($response);
    imagejpeg($img, 'download.jpg', 100);
}
```

`imagejpeg()` принимает три параметра: `resourse` - наш "ресурс", созданный с помощью `$img = imagecreatefromstring($response);`, `path` путь для сохранения нашей картинки, можете указать любой и `quality` - качество сохраняемого изображения. Далее уже зависит от вас, как вы будете распоряжаться сохраненной картинкой :)

Comment: не выводит даже и biography

Comment: @Mully По ссыке json же

Comment: да, json, мне нужно вывести с него инфу

Comment: Вы в вопросе написали получение картинки, картинка получена, инфу выводите с обращений через CURL. В ответе приложите структуру ответа, получаемого через ваш `$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1");`

Comment: не понял ничего

Comment: `var_dump($insta)`  сделайте, и приложите к вопросу

Comment: выводит NULL и больше ничего

Comment: `var_dump($response)` что выводит?

Answer (score 0):

Тут прям напрашивается `curl`

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), 1);

return $data['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url'];
```

Comment: при var_dump($data) выдает NULL и фотку не выводит тоже

Comment: @Kirill CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER почему 0?

Comment: Да так, на всяк. Самоподписанный сертификат может быть отклонён при CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=1. Данные в любом случае передаются по ssl

Comment: @Uvasya тогда проблема не в запросе. Я свой проверил.

Comment: @Kirill  самоподписный сертификат у инстаграма? :-) Решение с CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = 0 должно быть мотивированное и программист должен понимать, что это означает (уязвимость MITM, например). А копипаста -- зло.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один из вариантов - с передачей заголовка:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1");
$insta = json_decode($response, true);

header('Content-type:png');
readfile($insta['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url']);
```

Если понадобится сохранение в файл - используйте буферизацию.

Comment: readfile(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: @Uvasya -> [png](https://dropmefiles.com/VHhqf)